# Import project without lost library references

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm try to import an existing project into another workspace, but i'm not able to do it. For do it i follow this steps:

File->import->existing project into workspace

then i choose folder of my existing project, and import it. But project shows a lot of errors, that miss some libraries like android.support .
Where i'm wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of importing from

File->import->existing project into workspace

Try this

```
File->import->existing Android code into workspace from android sub menu
```

Comment: i obtain the same result

Comment: try to clean the project from 
 
Project--> clean

Comment: Else try to recreate the project and copy paste the class files that's the only solution.